# Email To Case-To Populate account and contact fields in case object based on existing Email Id In Contacts

Tags: email2case

How do I auto populate the Contact and Account fields in the Case object based on an existing contact when given an Email-ID. I'm encountering situations where the contact is populating properly but the account that it should be associated with is not. Is any customization required to make this happen? Thank you.

Comment: So, you receive an email from an emailAddress and the `Case.contactId` populates but not the `Case.accountId`? Does the case.accountId ever populate on an inbound emailToCase (for a new case)?  You have to consider that SFDC will try and match on Contact.email but that is not guaranteed unique across Contacts for the same account, let alone multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar does not support the function of auto-populating the contact or account. There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4nSAAQ) to implement this.

If using the button, salesforce will automatically set the contact or account.

The reason for this is that the button uses ["Email-to-Case"](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizesupport_email.htm&language=nl) which support the setting of the Case.Account and Case.Contact fields.

> Email-to-Case and On-Demand Email-to-Case help your company efficiently resolve customer inquiries via email. Salesforce automatically creates cases and auto-populates case fields when customers send messages to email addresses you specify.

Whereas the [side panel](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_side_panel_set_up_publisher.htm&language=en_US) uses publisher actions which essentially embeds the case page layout in Outlook, and just like the case page layout in browser you need to manually set those fields.